# What does `return $this->foo() === null` mean?

Tags: php, class, function, return

this is a code sample:

```
class md {
public function __construct() {
    if($this->getIsGuest()){
        echo 'iam guest';
    }
}
public function getIsGuest() {
    return $this->getState('__id')===null;
}
public function getState($val) {
    return '3';
}
```

is return $this->foo() === null is the default value of foo of nothing returned ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getIsGuest()` is returning the comparison of $this->getState('__id') to null.

If `$this->getState('__id')` returns exactly `null`, then `getIsGuest()` function returns true. If it returns anything except exactly `null`, then the `getIsGuest()` function returns false.

Comment: It's worth also adding that the `===` operator is like `==`, but instead of converting the types to the same ones, it will check equality, and also check that the types are actually the same too (or rather, checks the values are the same without trying to convert types).

Comment: +1, good point. I did not explain why I chose to say  'exactly null'.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that bit. I just remember being caught out by this, since 0 and '0' will also be type coerced to be null (I think).

Comment: @slugonamission: coerced to `null`, `empty`, `false`,... ah, the wonders of loose typing

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php - hopefully that will help further. Or, just make you facepalm harder.

Answer (score 0):

=== is type equality in php. In this case it would be used to tell the differencee between 0, '', false or the actual value null.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't all too good a sample, but there's nothing default-value-ish to it. What you *can* be sure of, is that the `getIsGuest` method will *always* return a boolean (either `true` or `false`). In your code snippet, it'll always return false, because it uses the return value of another method (`getState`) and compares it to `null` strictly (value *and* type). Since the `getState` member function is hard-coded to return a char in your example, it will *never* return null, and therefore, `getIsGuest` will *always* return false.

PHP has `null` as its default return value for all functions or methods that have no explicit return statement (with the possible exception of a constructor, which returns an instance of an object). Just like JS will return `undefined` by default (except constructors, again), or C functions can return `void`, but that's another matter. 
In short: no, your code isn't setting a default return value. I'll attempt to clarify all this by editing your snippet a bit:

```
class md
{
    private $_mdData = array();//no data
    public function __construct(array $params = null)//default value of $params is null
    {//the constructor expects either no parameters, or an array
        if ($params !== null)
        {
            $this->_mdData = $params;
        }
        if($this->getIsGuest())
        {
            echo 'I\'m guest';
        }
    }

    public function getIsGuest()
    {
        return $this->getState('__id') === null;
    }

    public function getState($val)
    {//return whatever value is stored in the private array under $val-key
     //if the key doesn't exist, null is returned
        return (isset($this->_mdData[$val]) ? $this->_mdData[$val] : null);
    }
}

$guest = new md();//no params
```

constructor calls getIsGuest, which tries to access $*mdData['*_id']
$_mdData is empty, so the key doesn't exist and null is returned to getIsGuest. 
getIsGuest compares the return value (null) to null, and returns true(because they are the same)
The constructor receives true, because that's where the `getIsGuest` method was called, and evaluates the value `if ($this->getIsGuest())` --> true, so `I'm a guest` is echoed.

```
$nonGuest = new md(array('__id'=>123));//same drill, only this time getState will return 123, and getIsGuest returns false
```

Now the difference between `==` and `===`:

```
$nullish = new md(array('__id' => ''));
```

This *won't* echo I'm a guest, *Unless* you were to change `return $this->getState('__id') === null;` to `return $this->getState('__id') == null;` because `''` an empty string is null-ish, like `0` is falsy etc...